How can I programatically not allow write operations on Oracle via ASP.NET?
I want a solution that does not include making a user with only query privileges. It's a safety measure on top of that.
it is for a monitoring tool that connect to databases that are not mine.
My aim was to rollback the transaction in a way that all write operations will not be committed.
I have a guard that protect the function from getting commits in a query, but it's not working.
I tried this method that worked on SQL Server and MySQL, but it's not working for me here. I test it with write operations and it is not working even that a rollback is called.
private async Task<List<Dictionary<string, object>>> ExecuteQueryAsync(string host, string connectionString, string query)
{
    var results = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

    try
    {
        await using var conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
        _logger.LogInformation($"[{DateTime.Now}] [Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] Attempting to open connection to {host} with connection string {connectionString}");
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        _logger.LogInformation($"[{DateTime.Now}] [Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] Successfully opened connection to {host}");

        var tran = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted); // Begin a transaction

        try
        {
            await using var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Transaction = tran; // Associate the transaction with the command

            await using var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                var row = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    var value = reader.IsDBNull(i) ? null : reader.GetValue(i);
                    row[reader.GetName(i)] = value;
                }

                results.Add(row);
            }
            
            await tran.RollbackAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await tran.RollbackAsync(); 
            _logger.LogError(ex, $"Error executing query on host {host}");
            throw; 
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, $"Error executing query on host {host}");
        var errorResult = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "host", host },
    { "Error", $"General error: {ex.Message}" }
};
        results.Add(errorResult);
    }

    return results;
}


If you don't want to allow write operations then connect as a database user that only has query privileges. (It's unclear what you mean about create/drop as that implies you're running multiple statements; but if you were, DDL operations implicitly commit so you can't roll back any earlier updates afterwards.)

I will edit so it will be more understandable.
For my use case i need the solution to be without making a new user.

Have you checked that you are setting auto-commit off for the connection? Different DBs and/or drivers might default that differently, so I'd explicitly set that to false if you aren't already.

The idea of using rollback as security measure is misplaced. I would not go down that route. You can of course use a combination of database permissions and program limitations (simply don't enable the write actions in your front-end if the user shouldn't have them). Construct your own security model within the front-end, allowing only the actions proper to the user in question - if they shouldn't have write, don't let them even try or know it's an option. If you do implement security on the back-end, it will have to be by using a different database account.

yes but its for a monitoring tool i dont want to limit the queries. the user write the query in a sql editor

You method of using ROLLBACK looks like it would fail when a user passes a PL/SQL statement that contains DML statements and then a COMMIT statement (since the ROLLBACK would only rollback to the last COMMIT).

i dont allow the user to use commit, using it will return him an error and wont pass the controller. it is for readonly but i connect to a lot of databases that are not mine, i want to add a code based safety measure on top of a readonly user.

If the user passes the statement BEGIN INSERT INTO table_name (id) VALUES (42); COMMIT; END; then they will both INSERT and COMMIT in the same statement and I don't see an obvious way that you are preventing that from happening as the ROLLBACK will only return you to the last COMMIT (which is after the INSERT).

There are several ways from the database:

Create a different user and grant them only SELECT privileges to the tables and then connect via that user.

Make the tables read-only
ALTER TABLE table_name READ ONLY;


Create a trigger for every table that raises an exception if an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE occurs on the table.
CREATE TRIGGER table_name__do_not_change__trg
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON table_name
  BEGIN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'table_name is read only');
  END;
/



fiddle

Under what circumstances would the third one be used?

@RobertHarvey Usually you would use something like that if you want to allow INSERT and not UPDATE or DELETE (removing the INSERT OR part) and didn't want a separate user (although you really should use a separate user) but it is an alternative if you want to effectively make a table read-only (although the other options are probably better for that purpose).
